# php exec(python) return unicode

Tags: php, python, unicode

I have a PHP script that calls a python script with arguments, and returns several string with `print` from python.

If python returns unicode characters, they won't show up properly in the browser.
If PHP sends unicode characters to python through arguments, it breaks.

**Python code:**

```
# -*- coding: UTF8 -*-
from lxml import html
hparser = html.HTMLParser(encoding="utf-8")
tree = html.parse(url, hparser)
## stuff here..
a = a_el.text.encode("utf-8")
b = b_el.text.encode("utf-8")
print [a, b]
```

**PHP code:**

```
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
exec('python script.py "unicode æøå"', $input_ar);

foreach ($input_ar as $value) {

    preg_match_all("/'([^']+)'/", $value, $value_ar);

    //A
    $a = $value_ar[1][0];
    //B
    $b = $value_ar[1][1];

    echo $a."<br>";
    echo $b."<br>";
}
```

The output in the browser either gives me `\xc3\c85` something or a question mark in a black diamond shape.
I've tried using `utf8_encode($string)`, but it didn't work.

I've also done a little research without luck.
I want to be able to send/recieve unicode characters from PHP to python.

Comment: all files must be UTF-8 also .. from your IDE try to change the File encoding to be UTF-8

Comment: The black diamond with a question mark is a replacement character. It represents characters that are not present in the characterset. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)

Comment: @MohammadAlabed I just tried with a python script that only had `print "æøå"` in it, and the question marks came up in the browser. After adding `# -*- coding: UTF8 -*-` at the top of the .py file, it worked fine. I changed the coding on my original script, but still get `\xc3\x85`. If I do `.encode("utf-8")` in python, I get `\xc3\x85` in the browser. If i remove it I get `\xc5`.

Comment: You also need to make sure that the python executable's stdout stream is UTF-8. Check it with `sys.stdout.encoding`

Comment: @theB PHP exec(python) returned `None` from `sys.stdout.encoding`. How to I change it?

Comment: In that case you probably want to refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/492711/5240004)

Comment: @theB tried the example you linked, but that is just what I'm doing. Since there's only 3 unicode characters, I can temporary solve it by replacing them with `#1#`, and change them back to their correct character in both python and php. I know, it's ugly, but it'll work for now.