# Python 2.7 unicode confusion again

Tags: python, linux, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I've already read this:

[Setting the correct encoding when piping stdout in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492483/setting-the-correct-encoding-when-piping-stdout-in-python#)

And I'm trying to stick with the rule of thumb: "*Always use Unicode internally. Decode what you receive, and encode what you send.*"

So here's my main file:

```
# coding: utf-8

import os
import sys

from myplugin import MyPlugin
if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = MyPlugin()
    a = unicode(open('myfile.txt').read().decode('utf8'))
    print(c.generate(a).encode('utf8'))
```

What is getting on my nerves is that:

- I read in a utf8 file so I decode it.
- then I force convert it to unicode which gives  `unicode(open('myfile.txt').read().decode('utf8'))`
- then I try to output it to a terminal
- on my Linux shell I need to re-encode it to utf8, and *I guess this is normal* because I'm working all this time on an unicode string, then to output it, I have to re-encode it in utf8 (correct me if I'm wrong here)
- when I run it with Pycharm under Windows, it's twice utf8 encoded, which gives me things like `agrÃ©able, dÃ©jÃ`. So if I remove `encode('utf8')` (which changes the last line to `print(c.generate(a))` then it works with Pycharm, but doesn't work anymore with Linux, where I get: `'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position` blabla you know the problem.

If I try in the command line:

- Linux/shell ssh: `import sys sys.stdout.encoding` I get `'UTF-8'`
- Linux/shell *in my code*: `import sys sys.stdout.encoding` I get `None` WTF??
- Windows/Pycharm: `import sys sys.stdout.encoding` I get `'windows-1252'`

What is the best way to code this so it works on both environments?

Comment: I like to use [codecs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/codecs.html) to open files in `utf-8` and always use `u"anystring"` inside the code. The file has to be saved in utf-8, of course. I haven't much problems then. If you're using IDE this has to be configured also to read utf-8 as default, also shell. This might not help you at all, but this is the way for me not to get into much encoding trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're philosophy is correct but you're over complicating things and making your code brittle.

Open files in text mode to automatically convert to Unicode for you. Then print without encoding - print is supposed to work out the correct encoding.

If your Linux environment isn't set correctly, then set `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` in your Linux environment vars (`export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8`) to fix up any issues during print. You should consider setting your locale to a UTF-8 variation such as `en_GB.UTF-8` to avoid having to define the `PYTHONIOENCODING`.

PyCharm should work without modification.

Your code should look like:

```
import os
import sys
import io

from myplugin import MyPlugin

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = MyPlugin()
    # t is the default
    with io.open('myfile.txt', 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
        # a is now a Unicode string
        a = myfile.read()

    result = c.generate(a)
    print result
```

If you're using Python 3.x, drop `import io` and `io.` from `io.open()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
unicode(open('myfile.txt').read().decode('utf8'))
```

no need to wrap with `unicode` because result of `str.decode` is already `unicode`.

```
print(c.generate(a).encode('utf8'))
```

no need to `encode` because Python will encode the string itself depending on the terminal encoding.

So this is the correct way to do

```
print(c.generate(a))
```

You are getting `'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position` because your Linux terminal has `ascii` encoding, so it's not possible for Python to print unicode characters to it.

See https://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails

I would suggest fixing your terminal (environment), not the code. You should not depend on the terminal encoding, especially as usually you print this info to a file.

If you still want to print it to any terminal which supports ASCII, you can use `str.encode('unicode-escape')`:

```
>>> print(u'щхжы'.encode('unicode-escape'))
\u0449\u0445\u0436\u044b
```

But it will be not very readable by humans, so I don't see the point.

Comment: You say that my terminal has ascii encoding so what I dont understand is why, if I launch python in my terminal as a command line, and try  sys.stdout.encoding I get 'UTF-8', whereas if I launch it with "python mymain.py", I get "None" as encoding?

Comment: If I try your sample in the shell, through python command line, `print u"\u03A9"` works whereas in the main file, it doesnt. Where could this problem come from?

Comment: Ok found the solution: my last line should be `print(c.generate(a).encode(sys.stdout.encoding))`

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails) > When Python does not detect the desired character set of the output, it sets sys.stdout.encoding to None, and print will invoke the "ascii" codec. < I don't know why it's like this in the case when you use a script.  How are you launching the script?

Comment: I'm launching it like this: `python myfile.py`

Comment: Are you doing any piping like `python myfile.py | cat`?

Comment: @OlivierPons See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492483/setting-the-correct-encoding-when-piping-stdout-in-python). Note this comment: "You should not be manually converting on each input and output of your program; that's brittle and completely unmaintainable."