# Unicode error in python program output

Tags: python, bash

I am trying run a bash command from my python program which out put the result in a file.I am using os.system to execute the bash command.But I am getting an error as follows:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201c' in position 793: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I am not able to understand how to handle it.Please suggest me a solution for it.

Comment: It's definitely time to use python 3, it simplifies a lot of encoding issues, and has been released for 7 years already, yes 7 years!

Comment: Hi akira, please post code for others to see.

Comment: @Akira How did you do? Has any of the solutions worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/what-does-unicodeerror-ascii-decoding-encoding-error-ordinal-not-in-range-128-mean.htm) Blog post

> These messages usually means that you’re trying to either mix Unicode strings with 8-bit strings, or is trying to write Unicode strings to an output file or device that only handles ASCII.

Try to do the following to encode your string:

> This can then be used to properly convert input data to Unicode. Assuming the string referred to by value is encoded as UTF-8:
>   `value = unicode(value, "utf-8")`

Comment: I actually don’t have a string.What my bash command do is it prints the result in the terminal.As I am using os.system so I am able to get the result in a variable.so I am including a file name using ‘>>’ in the bash command itself to store the terminal contenant to a file .How can convert terminal content to utf 8 before printing it to the file?

Comment: you can achieve this using `.encode()` - e.g. `print process.stdout.readline().encode("utf-8")`  have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492483/setting-the-correct-encoding-when-piping-stdout-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode your string as:

```
your_string =  your_string.encode('utf-8')
```

For example:

```
>>> print(u'\u201c'.encode('utf - 8'))
“
```

Comment: I actually don’t have a string.What my bash command do is it prints the result in the terminal.As I am using os.system so I am able to get the result  in a variable.so I am including a file name using ‘>>’ in the bash command itself to store the terminal contenant to a file .How can convert terminal content to utf 8 before printing it to the file?

Comment: @akire your result is saved in a string I assume. Show please what you are trying to print to the terminal. Also to correctly display unicode chars you system default environment should be set to utf-8. Do print sys.getdefaultencoding() if output is not utf-8, you should find in help of you IDE how to change environment to utf-8