# How to sort urdu words in python or bash

Tags: python

I have a text file that contains urdu words. I have to remove its duplicates. For that it is required that those words should be sorted. In english, its not a problem but when I follow same of urdu, then it became a problem (errors). For test case, suppose my text file contains floowing words (one word in each line for simplicity)

```
جنگ
بندی
 اس
کروانا
سات
 اس
سات
```

Following is the code and error.

```
[example@localhost compare]$ ./get_urdu_words.py |sort

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here get_urdu_words.py is a script that extract urdu words from a urdu/English mix file and sort is bash command.

This is the code of get_urdu_words.py

```
import re
test=u"جنگ بندی  اس کروانا سات  اس سات"

token=test.split(' ')
for w in token:
 status=re.search(ur'[\u0600-\u06ff]+',w)
 if status:
  print w
```

This question is specific to urdu language only

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: What code are you trying? Does the regular `sort` function not work on Urdu?

Comment: When I use `sort` on what you provided I don't get any errors (of course I don't know if they are really sorted according to the local convention or not, but I suppose with the correct locale it should work).

Comment: Re update: the error is in your `get_urdu_words.py`. Nothing to do with `sort` or bash.

Comment: Save your file as `utf-8`!

Comment: Please show you get_urdu_words.py file

Comment: Actually, this is the exact same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492483/setting-the-correct-encoding-when-piping-stdout-in-python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little modification should solve your problem.Try this one

```
import re
test=u"جنگ بندی  اس کروانا سات  اس سات"

token=test.split(' ')
for w in token:
 status=re.search(ur'[\u0600-\u06ff]+',w)
 if status:
  print w.encode('utf-8')
```

After this run this command

```
[example@localhost compare]$ ./get_urdu_words.py |sort
```