# Python2.7 print unicode string still getting UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character ... ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, python-unicode

A simple print function

```
def TODO(message):
    print(type(message))
    print(u'\n~*~ TODO ~*~ \n %s\n     ~*~\n' % message)
```

called like this

```
TODO(u'api servisleri için input check decorator gerekiyor')
```

results in this error

```
<type 'unicode'>                                                                                 
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                               
  File "/srv/www/proj/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>                                      
    TODO(u'api servisleri için input check decorator gerekiyor')                                 
  File "/srv/www/proj/helpers/utils.py", line 33, in TODO                                     
    print(u'\n~*~ TODO ~*~ \n %s\n     ~*~\n' % message)                                         
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe7' in position 32: ordinal not in range(128)
```

But it works in ipython console

```
In [10]: TODO(u'api servisleri için input check decorator gerekiyor')
<type 'unicode'>

~*~ TODO ~*~ 
 api servisleri için input check decorator gerekiyor
     ~*~
```

This works with python 2.7.12 but fails somehow with 2.7.9.

What is it that am i doing wrong here?

Edit: function fails when called in a flask application, works in python console.

Comment: I just tried your code on multiple versions of python, 2.6.6, 2.7.9, 2.7.10 and 2.7.13, from the command line, and your code worked fine.

Comment: It sounds like your console locale is broken and has defaulted to ASCII. What OS are you using?

Comment: I assume you're on a Un*x system. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35839964/1554386

Comment: With no further information, I vote to close this as "not reproducible". This is likely to be a simple locale issue.

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack Mint 18 on local and debian jessie on remote. locale command outputs the same on both systems. It was failing on the remote machine, yet it seems that the local one had a problem since it should have failed but hadn't. please see my answer for the details.

Comment: On your failing system, run the following in both iPython and Python: `import locale; locale.getpreferredencoding()`.

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack both are 'UTF-8'

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack my bad, i didn't mention that i was receiving this error when the function is called in a flask application. it works in (i)python interactive sessions. I guess there's something related to flask's settings.

Comment: How do you start flask?

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack within the same environment i start the interactive consoles. there's no settings related to encoding in flask project and the documents do not mention anything on flask having any effect on project's encoding settings

Comment: Something in Flask must be changing it. Can you call `locale.getpreferredencoding()` and `locale.getdefaultlocale()` at the top of your flask code before you do any imports, once you've configured the app and once inside your method?

Comment: Having the same problem too. Two computer, same python version , both prints the same getpreferredencoding, getdefaultlocale and still only one of them fails on python print when having special utf-8 character

Answer (score 0):

Different terminals (and GUIs) allow different encodings.  I don't have a recent ipython handy, but it is apparently able to handle the non-ASCII `0xe7` character (`'ç'`) in your string.  Your normal console, however, is using the `'ascii'` encoding (mentioned by name in the exception), which can't display any bytes greater than `0x7f`.

If you want to print non-ASCII strings to an ASCII console, you'll have to decide what to do with the characters it can't display.  The `str.encode` method offers several options:

> `str.encode([encoding[, errors]])`
>
> `errors` may be given to set a different error handling scheme.
>   The default for `errors` is `'strict'`, meaning that encoding errors raise a [`UnicodeError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.UnicodeError).
>   Other possible values are `'ignore'`, `'replace'`, `'xmlcharrefreplace'`, `'backslashreplace'` and any other name registered via [`codecs.register_error()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.register_error), see section [Codec Base Classes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codec-base-classes).

Here's an example that uses each of those four alternative error-handlers on your string (without the extra decoration added by `TODO`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import print_function

uni = u'api servisleri için input check decorator gerekiyor'
handlers = ['ignore', 'replace', 'xmlcharrefreplace', 'backslashreplace']
for handler in handlers:
    print(handler + ':')
    print(uni.encode('ascii', handler))
    print()
```

The output:

```
ignore:
api servisleri iin input check decorator gerekiyor

replace:
api servisleri i?in input check decorator gerekiyor

xmlcharrefreplace:
api servisleri i&#231;in input check decorator gerekiyor

backslashreplace:
api servisleri i\xe7in input check decorator gerekiyor
```

Which one of those outputs comes closest to what you want is for you to decide.

For more information, see the Python 2 "[Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)", and Ned Batchelder's "[Pragmatic Unicode, or, How Do I Stop the Pain?](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html)", also available as a 36 minute [video from PyCon US 2012](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgHbC6udIqc).

**Edit**:  ...or, as you seem to have discovered, your terminal can display Unicode just fine, but your default encoding is nevertheless set to `'ascii'`, which is more restrictive than it needs to be.

Answer (score -1):

> \xe7

One of the utf-8 character that represents small 'ç'. Python 2.7.9 probably encode with ASCII. You can run the code below in any version of Python that represents Python 2.7.9's behaviour.

```
import sys; 
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def TODO(message):
    print(type(message))
    print(u'\n~*~ TODO ~*~ \n %s\n     ~*~\n' % message)

message = u'api servisleri için input check decorator gerekiyor'
encodedMessage = message.encode('ascii')

print(sys.stdout.encoding)
TODO(encodedMessage)
```

It will throw the exception

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 9, in
>   
>       encodedMessage = message.encode('ascii') UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe7' in position 16: ordinal
>   not in range(128)

So, issue is related with interpreter's encoding rules. You can encode on your own or ignore.

Hope it will be useful

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, print function is a bit different from the print statement.

https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#print

```
All non-keyword arguments are converted to strings like 
str() does and written to the stream, separated by sep 
and followed by end.
```

Simply, encoding the unicode string solved it

```
msg = u'\n~*~ TODO ~*~ \n %s\n     ~*~\n' % message
print(msg.encode("utf-8"))
```

Still, not sure why it works with 2.7.12, maybe a locale thing?

Comment: This isn't the answer.  See @Alastair comment and fix your environment.  What you are doing is manually encoding to UTF-8, which wouldn't work on a non-UTF8 terminal.  Configure your terminal to report UTF-8 correctly to Python and `print u'için'` will work.  Print function vs. statement is a red herring, Python 2 doesn't have print function unless you use `from __future__ import print_function`.  It changes to a function in Python 3.

Comment: Both environments have the same locale output. And as stated in the document I have mentioned, this is the expected output of print function. this is the output of print on the machine that the print function failed. `╰─$ python 
Python 2.7.9 (default, Jun 29 2016, 13:08:31) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print u'için'
için`