# Python 3 array with UTF-16 chars

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-16

I created two arrays with positive and negative emojis by using the emojis' unicode value:

```
positive = [
u'\U0001F600',
u'\U0001F601',
u'\U0001F602',
u'\U0001F923',
u'\U0001F603',
u'\U0001F604',
u'\U0001F605',
u'\U0001F606',
u'\U0001F609',
u'\U0001F60A',
u'\U0001F60B',
u'\U0001F60E',
u'\U0001F60D',
u'\U0001F618',
u'\U0001F617',
u'\U0001F619',
u'\U0001F61A',
u'\U0000263A',
u'\U0001F642',
u'\U0001F917',
u'\U0001F60F',
u'\U0001F60C',
u'\U0001F61B',
u'\U0001F61C',
u'\U0001F61D',
u'\U0001F924',
u'\U0001F643',
u'\U0001F62C']

negative = [
u'\U0001F610',
u'\U0001F611',
u'\U0001F636',
u'\U0001F644',
u'\U0001F60F',
u'\U0001F623',
u'\U0001F625',
u'\U0001F62E',
u'\U0001F910',
u'\U0001F62F',
u'\U0001F62A',
u'\U0001F62B',
u'\U0001F634',
u'\U0001F612',
u'\U0001F613',
u'\U0001F614',
u'\U0001F615',
u'\U0001F641',
u'\U0001F616',
u'\U0001F61E',
u'\U0001F61F',
u'\U0001F624',
u'\U0001F622',
u'\U0001F62D',
u'\U0001F626',
u'\U0001F627',
u'\U0001F628',
u'\U0001F629',
u'\U0001F630',
u'\U0001F631',
u'\U0001F635',
u'\U0001F621',
u'\U0001F620',
u'\U0001F637',
u'\U0001F912',
u'\U0001F915',
u'\U0001F922',
u'\U0001F927']
```

But when I print positive[0], for example, I get back this weird character instead of an emoji:

```
�
```

I'm working on an EC2 machine with Amazon Linux and using python-3.4.
Same code works as expected from my Macbook.

Comment: I get an emoji.

Comment: Works for me too on the macOS terminal. Probably has to do with what console emulator you're using.

Comment: This depends on the end-user environment being able to interpret the unicode set. The particular font may not have a character to represent the intended character and so shows a default character (i.e. diamond with question mark).

Comment: the problem is with "screen", it works fine if i'm not running under it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not a Python Issue. The Mac supports fonts in the terminal that can print those unicode characters.

Those same fonts are not supported in the case you are using.

If the device in question were to support those unicode values they would print properly.

I tested a standard macOS SSH Terminal to Ubuntu and that worked as does native Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Hello [Daniel Haviv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1028318/daniel-haviv),

Try this if it works:

`print(positive[0].encode('utf-8'))`

You can read more here [Python 2.x’s Unicode Support](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#python-2-x-s-unicode-support)

**Update:** The previous solution did not worked for you try this:

```
import sys
import codecs
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout)

print(positive[0])
```

I found the solution from [Setting the correct encoding when piping stdout in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492483/setting-the-correct-encoding-when-piping-stdout-in-python)

Comment: I'm using Python 3 and UTF-16. encode('utf-8') returned: \xf0\x9f\x91\x8d'

Comment: @DanielHaviv, Python 3 has the same syntax. What do you mean by `UTF-16`? You mean you tried `print(positive[0].encode('UTF-16'))`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I was running under [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html)

Comment: Hello again Daniel Haviv. Can you also run one more the update code that I have added with screen to check. It would be nice for future reference to know. BR