# Can markdown2.py render as utf-8?

Tags: python, utf-8, markdown

When converting utf-8 encoded text to html using `markdown2.py`, the result is ASCII encoded. How can I tell markdown2 to render utf-8?

Sample input file called `ff.md`:

```
Hallo, Bjørn Nößflögl
```

transformed using:

```
C:\Python37\python.exe C:\Python37\Scripts\markdown2.py ff.md
```

When I open the result in an editor (Notepad++), it thinks it's ASCII. Likewise when I render it using `flask`'s `render_template` it crashes on the diacritics. (`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf8 in position 12: invalid start byte`)

If I manually convert to utf-8 with Notepad++, everything's fine.

Glancing briefly over the markdown2 code, I can see input when read is assumed to be utf-8. So I don't understand why it's not rendered as such.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Thanks for the suggestion, however in the console first `chcp 65001` and then converting the file still renders it as ASCII. The ö comes becomes `\xf6`  (ASCII), not '\xc3\xb6'. I guess I'll have to dive into markdown2.py if I get tired of the workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** Set the system variable PYTHONIOENCODING to utf-8.

**Explanation**: To do that in Windows 10, hit the Windows key, type `environment` and launch *Edit environment variables for your account*. Click New and set `Name of` to `PYTHONIOENCODING` and `Value` of to `utf-8`, note no quotes. Save. Doing it this way will make Windows retain that setting.

In the [Markdown2](https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2/blob/master/lib/markdown2.py) code, these lines write the file in my case (Python 3).

```
if py3:
    sys.stdout.write(html)
```

Googling 'python sys.stdout.write utf8' led me to [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/492483/1016065), where [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4027726/1016065) led me to the solution.