# hello. I'm learning django. I downloaded small project from git hub and problem is intalling requrement.txt

Tags: python, django, github

how can i install requirement.txt? created project with different virtual environment(pipenv and venv) but in the end

```
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [10 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-x_oh84s8\django-localized-names_d98dfe1d2720418d895d5cf15016e5dd\setup.py", line 17, in <module>
          long_description=read('README.rst'),
        File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-x_oh84s8\django-localized-names_d98dfe1d2720418d895d5cf15016e5dd\setup.py", line 8, in read
          return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname)).read()
        File "C:\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode
          return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
      UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 2468: character maps to <undefined>
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

how can I fix it please?

Comment: There's an unexpected character in `README.rst` preventing the installation.

Comment: Can you change the [encoding used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/492483/6309)? At least `set PYTHONIOENCODING utf-8`