# python print method will raise encoding error when following | or > in powershell on windows

Tags: python, powershell, gbk

Given the following python script `test.py`

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print("Er, Süleyman")
```

Here is the result of running this script in powershell

```
python test.py  # success
Er, Süleyman


python test.py > tmp.txt
    print("Er, Süleyman")
UnicodeEncodeError: 'gbk' codec can't encode character '\u0308' in position 6: illegal multibyte sequence

python test.py | Out-File -Encoding utf8 tmp.txt
    print("Er, Süleyman")
UnicodeEncodeError: 'gbk' codec can't encode character '\u0308' in position 6: illegal multibyte sequence
```

I have no idea about how to wrong around this.

The default language of my laptop is Chinese, by running the following code, I get the output `cp936`.

```py
import locale
print(locale.getpreferredencoding())
```

I also try write buffer directly and the error is gone, but the content is incorrect.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
sys.stdout.buffer.write("Er, Süleyman".encode('utf-8'))
```

```
python test.py > test.txt
cat test.txt
Er, Su虉leyman
```

### Update

I found a solution to change the default encoding of powershell in this answer: [Using UTF-8 Encoding (CHCP 65001) in Command Prompt / Windows Powershell (Windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131654/using-utf-8-encoding-chcp-65001-in-command-prompt-windows-powershell-window/57134096#57134096)

> In PSv5.1 or higher, where > and >> are effectively aliases of Out-File, you can set the default encoding for > / >> / Out-File via the $PSDefaultParameterValues preference variable:
>
> `$PSDefaultParameterValues['Out-File:Encoding'] = 'utf8'`

Though it is not a problem of Python, but without knowledge of the difference among the default encoding of Python Stdout, Windows and Powershell, it will be hard to find the right solution. For example, [Setting the correct encoding when piping stdout in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492483/setting-the-correct-encoding-when-piping-stdout-in-python) is trying to fix from the Python's side but in fact it will introduce a new problem: force stdout to use `gtk` encoding will end up with some unsupported chars are displayed incorrectly.  So I think this issue still have value for those who are not familiar with such complicated situation.

Comment: Anyway, you need to set the encoding used by `sys.stdout`, so that it matches the default that your operating system is using for file I/O. Please see the linked duplicate. (You also need to set up your system *so that it uses an encoding for files that is able to represent the text you want to use*. That part is a "how do I use my computer" question, not a programming question; try [windows.se] for that.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492483/setting-the-correct-encoding-when-piping-stdout-in-python I have try this method and it ends up writing successfully, but the content is incorrect.

Comment: You will also need to make sure that *whatever you use to open (and verify) the file, also understands* the encoding that was used. Please keep in mind that **files only ever contain bytes**; an encoding is an *interpretation* of data that is *not intrinsic* to that data. Even if it's ASCII.

Comment: No, that isn't strange at all. It works fine when outputting to the terminal *because the terminal has a different encoding setting* vs. what the operating system defaults to for files. The terminal is implemented by Powershell; the file I/O is implemented by Windows, and Powershell is only an interface to that (shell redirection does not give a way to specify the file encoding).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I see. Thank you for the explaination, now it is clear to me. I have try chaning the encoding used by sys.stdout, but it ends up writing wrong chars in the file. Can I temporary change the Windows' default encoding of writting file, for example, by exporting some environment variables in powershell?

Comment: We would need a more specific, detailed [mre] - including the way that you verify the file contents (it will be better to show the actual **bytes** you end up with, along with explaining how you intend to open and view the file normally).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I think they are already there. I just add one more case.